# Retrieve posts using thumbnail id as meta key

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

I am working on my website and using these args in wp_query but I also want to show only those posts which have thumbnails in it... here are the args I am working on:

```
        $args1 = array(
            'posts_per_page'        => $number,
            'no_found_rows'         => true,
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'offset'                => $offset,
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
            'orderby'               => $sort_order,
            'meta_key'              => ( ($sort_order == 'meta_value_num') ? 'mip_post_views_count' : '' )
        );

        $args2  = array();
        if ($include_categories) {
            //$include_categories = explode(",", $include_categories);
            $args2 = array(
                'cat'      => $include_categories
            );
        }
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
    $args1 = array(
            'posts_per_page'        => $number,
            'no_found_rows'         => true,
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'offset'                => $offset,
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
            'orderby'               => $sort_order,
            'meta_key'              => ( ($sort_order == 'meta_value_num') ? 'mip_post_views_count' : '' ),
            // this is what is added
            'meta_query'    => '_thumnail_id'
        );

        $args2  = array();
        if ($include_categories) {
            //$include_categories = explode(",", $include_categories);
            $args2 = array(
                'cat'      => $include_categories
            );
        }
```

But it changes the order of the posts...can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting an array for `meta_query` instead, I do not think using just a string for it is the intended usage, but this may work instead in your case:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    )
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm...but can I know the issue with mine?

Comment: seems just providing a string for querying without an operator is insufficient information for this parameter... all the example in the codex provide a `key` and a `value` and an `operator`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
but you can get away without the `value` here.